# How to prevent Visual Studio Code Python debugger from stopping on handled exceptions?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode 1.30.2 with ms-python 2019.1.0 (29 Jan 2019)
The debugger stops at any handled exceptions in my code, although I can continue debugging, but I'd rather not stop at them because at times there are many exceptions being raised and caught.
It only stops on my own code exceptions, not on the imported modules, for example `hasattr()`
I'm not using virtual environments.
Is there a way to unset this?

Comment: note: opposite question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74732547/11107541). Also related: [While debugging, how can I break on raised exceptions EXCEPT FOR specific errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63247025/11107541) with a nice answer.

Answer (score 11):

You just have to uncheck *Raised Exceptions* in the breakpoints panel.

[image]