# While debugging, how can I break on raised exceptions EXCEPT FOR specific errors?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

I use Visual Studio Code for Python development.

In general, I want my IDE to break whenever an exception is raised, so I have the `Raised Exceptions` option checked under the Debug window:

[image]

However, there is a specific (encoding-related) exception I would like to ignore because it is raised thousands of times per second. I wrap it in a try-except blocks but, as expected, it breaks when the exception is thrown. I want to suppress this behavior but only for a specific error type.

Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: so you want only break on `Uncaught Exceptions`

Comment: @rioV8: I don't think so. I _need_ to catch the exception otherwise the application will fail. i.e. I need the application to handle the exception gracefully so I need a try-except statement... I just don't want the IDE to stop every time that particular exception is raised.   So maybe exceptions can be configured in settings.json? I don't know.

Comment: remove the tick on `Raised Exceptions`, then all exceptions handled by a try-catch will not bother your debugging, only the ones that will bubble to the top of the stack

Comment: Thanks, @rioV8. Unfortunately, that won't work for my purposes. In general, I want to know if exceptions are raised, even if it happens in a try-catch block. It's just one specific exception type that I want to ignore.

Comment: if you want to know if the exception happens inside the try catch, put a log-breakpoint inside the catch handler, you get a message text in the debug output: Run | New Breakpoint | Logpoint

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm on the same boat.. I want to break on Raised Exceptions, but only of a specific type of error

Comment: Unfortunately not, no. I don't recall exactly, but there's a good chance I added code to avoid the exception being raised. It's not "pythonic"; but I'm an adult.

Comment: I had a similar issue.  Breaking on every raised exception was ridiculous,   but I wanted to find my exception before it popped up the stack.  But so many exceptions are handled routinely, by design, and the debugger doesn't know to ignore those.

Comment: Although perhaps not a full solution, it would be great if **vscode** could at least have an *option to automatically turn on the "raised exceptions" checkbox* any time you stop in the debugger (and re-disable it whenever you resume with `F5`). This way, you could free-run to a breakpoint on the code of interest, and then get the raised exceptions if you start single-stepping from there. Barring this feature in vscode, you can always use the same technique manually, perhaps to some avail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a couple settings available for configuring **Python** exception behavior when debugging in **VScode**. For the following examples, we assume that the checkboxes **Raised Exceptions** and **Uncaught Exceptions** are both *checked* (enabled). This is normally a situation where there the debugger is stopping for lots of unwanted exceptions.

**Intro**
Consider the following example. For this code, the debugger will stop at the three places indicated.

```py
    try:
        1 / 0                # FIRST STOP
    except:
        pass

    func = lambda: 1 / 0     # SECOND STOP
    try:
        func()               # THIRD STOP
    except:
        pass
```

Note that the exception that causes the "second stop" notated above doesn't occur at the point in the code where variable *func* is assigned. Indeed, being outside of a `try-except` block, such code would otherwise cause the program to exit. Instead, of course, the exception happens later on *nested within* the delayed invocation, which thankfully *is* protected by `try`. This distinction will become important for an example further below.

**1. Line annotation**
 The first technique allows you to prevent the debugger from breaking on exceptions at specific locations in your code. Put the special `@IgnoreException` token in a comment on the desired line or lines. See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/blob/514e54fa2b87951e571ac5b6596c461f6644432a/src/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_frame.py#L51) for the RegEx forms of this tag which the debugger will recognize.

```
    try:
        1 / 0                #@IgnoreException
    except:
        pass

    func = lambda: 1 / 0     #@IgnoreException
    try:
        func()               #@IgnoreException
    except:
        pass
```

This is great for specialized, fine-grained control of where the debugger stops, but obviously as a more general solution, this approach will quickly get out-of-hand. Before moving on from this though, note that there is a way to globally enable or disable the `@IgnoreException` behavior in the debugger.

This feature is enabled by default when the debugger starts; if that's all you need you can skip this section. To globally disable `@IgnoreException` handling, you can either just insert the following snippet where it executes once at the start of your program or, if desired, instrument your code to programatically enable and disable `@IgnoreException` handling according to runtime conditions as needed. A `try-except` block prevents the code from crashing when it's not being debugged or if the debugger isn't installed.

```
    # To enable or disable @IgnoreException handling when pydevd is active:
    #    'True'  - debugger won't stop on '@IgnoreException` lines (default)
    #    'False' - the annotation are ignored, allowing the debugger to stop

    try:
        import pydevd
        d = pydevd.GetGlobalDebugger()
        d.ignore_exceptions_thrown_in_lines_with_ignore_exception = False
    except:
        pass
```

**2. Context-aware ignore**
Moving on to the second option, I'll reset back to the original code, without the line annotations. This time, by changing the value of a secret debugger switch, the debugger will only stop on exceptions which are raised outside of the caller's immediate context. This is the `skip_on_exceptions_thrown_in_same_context` debugger flag, and it is **not** enabled by default, so if you want this behavior, you have to explicitly turn it on (as shown):

```
    try:
        from pydevd import GetGlobalDebugger
        GetGlobalDebugger().skip_on_exceptions_thrown_in_same_context = True
    except:
        pass

    try:
        1 / 0
    except:
        pass

    func = lambda: 1 / 0
    try:
        func()         # ONLY STOP
    except:
        pass
```

Now the debugger only stops one time, versus stopping on three raised exceptions previously, in the first example. And I know what you're thinking, now it makes more sense to combine these two approaches, since there will typically be far fewer points in most code that will need annotating with `@IgnoreException`.

**3. Combine both techniques**
So here's the final version of the example which, even with both the *RaisedExceptions* and *UncaughtExceptions* options enabled, the **VScode** debugger runs all the way through without stopping:

```
    try:
        from pydevd import GetGlobalDebugger
        GetGlobalDebugger().skip_on_exceptions_thrown_in_same_context = True
    except: pass

    try:
        1 / 0
    except:
        pass

    func = lambda: 1 / 0
    try:
        func()     #@IgnoreException
    except:
        pass
                   # NO DEBUGGER STOPS...
```