# How can I configure VS Code to break on any unhandled exception in a Python3 application when debugging unittest tests

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

I am sure this used to work before, and I cannot figure out if there is a setting I changed or anything else.

If I debug a test, and there is an unhandled/uncaught exception, the test stops and I get this screen:
[image]

How can I get back the behaviour so that the test breaks at the point of the exception?

Comment: note: opposite question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54519728/11107541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have most likely involuntarily unchecked the top boxes in the Breakpoints panel. Check them and things should work as expected again:
[image]

Most likely when you manually unchecked all the breakpoints.

Instead, use the little icon in the top right corner, since that one will not uncheck the top three.

Comment: I did not know this before, but it seems that you cannot actually do this immediately. But I will as soon as I am allowed to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/